# how do I get the 'tool' back to my selection?

Tags: modeling

[image: description of problem]

I can't figure out how on earth I get the tool back to normal mode..... right now it's stuck at whereever my cursor-thing is located.

I can switch between 4 modes, but none of them get's me back at how it was.

I tried deleting the program and reinstalling because I can't figure it out and it seems like such a small thing, probably some hotkey I miss-clicked. Anyways, after deleting and reinstalling it just starts up with the same UI :(

such a small thing can be so god damn annoying!

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>,</kbd> (Comma), it will set it back to the center

[image]

Circled in green are the options that will return your manipulator widget to the correct location. The one in red is where you have it set now, which is why it is at the 3d cursor.

You can also change it at the bottom of the 3d view.